# Elastic Search with Nest match query not working

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to do a Match query using Nest using C#. The Match  query does not return any results as the syntax of produced JSON seems off, I know for sure that there are documents that contains this keyword. 
Here is the C# code snippet

```
var response = conn.Search<DelOrder>(x => x
        .From(0)
        .Size(1000)
        .Query(q => q
               .Match
               (m => m
                    .Field(f => f.customerName).Query(searchValue)
                    .Analyzer("standard")))
```

this produces following query:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 1000,
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "customerName": {
                "**query**": "star",
                "analyzer": "standard"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This query, returns 0 results, however when I tweak the same query in Kibana console
Get _search

```
{
    "from":0,
    "size":1000,
    "query": 
    {
        "match":
        {
            "customername":"star"
        }
```

I get results for the searched term. Notice that the "second query token" is missing from the syntax of the Kibana query.

I did check  the documentation and it seem my syntax is correct
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/match-usage.html

Any thoughts on what is going on or how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the NEST query

1. the standard analyzer is specified whilst the query executed in Kibana does not include this
2. uses `customerName` for the field name, inferred from the member expression `f => f.customerName`, whilst Kibana uses `customername` (lower case `n`)

If you amend the NEST query to match the Kibana query, you'll get the results you're expecting.

Comment: thanks, I was able to get the field names to match and now the query that is being sent to search server is correct and works in Kibana but I get 0 count back from the C# code. Get _search
{"from":0,"size":100,"query":{"match":{"customercompanyname":{"query":"navistar","analyzer":"standard"}}}} which is strange at best

Comment: @Andy are you targeting the same indices (and types, if relevant) for the search request with both NEST and Kibana?

Comment: Yes, same index, only one type doc. Term and wild card queries are working with same connection settings

Comment: @andy Can you share the exact queries being sent by both NEST and Kibana, including URI, and the results, either as an edit to question or a gist? Do both specify using the `standard` analyzer?